# Stuck inside a wall, how can I get out?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

In Assassin's Creed: Odyssey (PC), I made the mistake of doing a Rush Assassination against a dog that was stuck in a wall. Now the dog is dead, but I'm stuck in the wall. (To be *technically* correct, I'm stuck in the floor. The ground under the Temple of Athena Itonia in Boeotia is apparently uneven, so there are gaps between the floor and the ground, and I'm now stuck under there.)

Since this is a hostile area, I can't fast travel away and come back. I can move around a bit, but can't climb out. I'm quite literally underneath a solid floor. The edges/walls do come flush up to the ground, so I can't slip out through there. And I've killed all the other bandits in the temple, so I can't Rush Assassinate myself back out.

**Is there any way to 'clip' out of here, or do I need to reload from a previous autosave, losing my progress?**

[image: Under the floor]

When I run to the edges of the temple, I can move the camera and see that I'm quite literally one with the architecture now:

[image: Be one with the wall...]

Comment: Can you kill yourself using explosive arrows?

Comment: Killing myself with explosive arrows will result in loss of progress by reloading from the last save. I could just skip the suicide part and reload directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but if you don't find any climbable points, or you cannot exit usings attacks, you have no way to get out, and you will need to reload. I had various stuck problems like this in AC: Syndacate (PC).

Comment: Odyssey fixed many of the issues in earlier games, so just because it happened a certain way in Sindicate doesn't necessarily mean there's no solution in Odyssey.

Comment: You are right, but I don't know the existence of other way to get out if climbing/using abilities doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly what I had to do. Reload the last checkpoint. Had this happen 2-3 times in my ACO run.